# For loop refactoring?

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-cleanup

Given the array nums consisting of 2n elements in the form [x1,x2,...,xn,y1,y2,...,yn].

Return the array in the form [x1,y1,x2,y2,...,xn,yn].

Example 1:

Input: nums = [2,5,1,3,4,7], n = 3

Output: [2,3,5,4,1,7]

```
public int[] Shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.Length];
    
    int z = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < (2 * n); x += 2) {
        result[x] = nums[z]; 
        z++;
    }
    
    z = 0;

    for (int y = n; y < (2 * n); y++) {
        result[z + 1] = nums[y];
        z += 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, describe in plain English what does the routine do?

Comment: Do you have any specific question?

Comment: Specific question: How is the best way ( code clean and refactoring ) to resolve that problem?

Comment: The code make the work, but it's ugly.

Comment: `Shuffle` is a pretty poor name for this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we go:

```
void Main()
{
    var nums = new[] { 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 7 };
    
    var result = Shuffle(nums, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", result));
}

public int[] Shuffle(int[] nums, int n) =>
    nums
        .Take(n)
        .Zip(nums.Skip(n), (x, y) => new[] { x, y })
        .SelectMany(z => z)
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me:

```
2,3,5,4,1,7
```

Or this:

```
public int[] Shuffle(int[] nums, int n) =>
(
    from zs in nums.Take(n).Zip(nums.Skip(n), (x, y) => new[] { x, y })
    from z in zs
    select z
).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute which item should be placed at `i`-th index:

```
public static int[] Shuffle(int[] nums) {
  // Since we have public method, we should validate input
  if (null == nums)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nums));

  if (nums.Length % 2 != 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(nums));

  int[] result = new int[nums.Length];

  // All we have to do is to place right item at i-th index:
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i)
    result[i] = nums[i / 2 + (i % 2) * (nums.Length / 2)];

  return result;
}
```

Note, that we can get rid of `n`, since we can easily compute it as `n == nums.Length / 2`.

Same idea implemented via Linq:

```
public static int[] Shuffle(int[] nums) {
  if (null == nums)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nums));

  if (nums.Length % 2 != 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(nums));

  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, nums.Length)
    .Select(i => nums[i / 2 + (i % 2) * (nums.Length / 2)])
    .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for your explanation. I'm tring to improve in Loop refactoring using Linq and your explanation is a good way to learn.